# Ember - Rerender the screen after change to the model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Hello all and thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Instead of providing code I will explain the approaches I've tried as well as I'll simplify the problem I'm trying to solve.

Two models:

```
Team:
hasMany ProjectTeams
```

and

```
ProjectTeam:
belongsTo Team
value: int
```

All of this is happening in the TeamRoute and team.hbs template.

I iterate over all the projectTeams for a particular Team and render a textfield whose value attribute I bind to the value attribute of the ProjectTeam model (so that when one of the is updated, the changes are propagated to the other.)

All of the projectTeams are rendered in a `<table>` and each `<tr>` corresponds to a `ProjectTeam`

Now I would like to sort the ProjectTeams for each of the Team by the following criteria:

All projectTeams with value=0 should go to the bottom of the table. The rest should be at the top.

That would mean that whenever I input 0 into one of the elements which were empty or had other values in them, this record should automatically go to the bottom, and conversely, if I add a value to a field that had initially a value of 0, it should be moved somewhere in the upper half of the table (a.k.a the page should be rerendered).

What I did was I decided to send to the template an ordered collection. I am ordering the collection in TeamController like so:

```
App.TeamController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
  sortProps: ["value"]
  sortedArray: Ember.computed.sort("content.projectTeams", "sortProps")
)
```

and then in the template I've got:

```
{{#each projectTeams itemController='projectTeam'}}
  <td>
     {{view Ember.TextField content=this value=value}}
  </td>
{{/each}}
```

When the page is initially loaded the projectTeams are ordered correctly, meaning, the ones with value=0 are at the bottom of the table. However, whenever I try to change the value of any of them, the clicked character is registered (shown on the screen), and focus is lost from the textfield. I suspect this is due to the fact that, since there's been a change to the original array, the controller is called (TeamController) and it is resorting the array. Also, the content is NOT reordered after the change occurs which is very strange because I was thinking that the focusout problem was due to the fact that the collection is reordered!..

My question would be whether someone could provide a jsfiddle whereby in a team template, projectTeams are listed, and whenever a value for any of the projectTeams is changed, the whole template is rerendered correctly?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is the 0 value being persisted to the model?